# Most common occurrence of a name in a string compile error

Tags: swift

I am writing a function that returns a dictionary that contains the name with most occurrences as the `key` and the number of occurrences as the `value`, however, I get an error - see the code below:

```
let names = ["Adam", "Bob", "Charlie", "Dylan", "Edward"]    

func getMostCommonName(array: [String]) -> [String: Int] {

    var namesDictionary: [String: Int] = [:]  // holds all the names and their occurrences
    var mostCommonNames: [String: Int] = [:]  // will hold the most common name(s) and their occurrences

    for name in array {
        if let count = namesDictionary[name] {
            namesDictionary[name] = count + 1
        }
        else {
            namesDictionary[name] = 1
        }
    }

    let highestOccurence = namesDictionary.values.max()

    for name in namesDictionary {
        if namesDictionary[name] == highestOccurence {
            mostCommonNames[name] = highestOccurence // throws an error
        }
    }

    return mostCommonNames
}

getMostCommonName(array: names)
```

The error is `Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : Int]' with an index of type '(key: String, value: Int)'`. I really don't understand why it would throw this error. Any takers?

Comment: FYI - The entire `if/else` of your first `for` loop can be replaced with `namesDictionary[name, default: 0] += 1`

Comment: FYI - And your entire second `for` loop can be replaced with `mostCommonNames = namesDictionary.filter { $0.value == highestOccurence }`

Comment: I see, that's true. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because name is type of `(key: String, value: Int)`,it is tuple type，you can access key and value like this

```
for element in namesDictionary {
    if element.value == highestOccurence {
        mostCommonNames[element.key] = highestOccurence
    }
}
```

Also, I recommend to write `for in` like this

```
for (key,value) in namesDictionary {
    if value == highestOccurence {
        mostCommonNames[key] = highestOccurence
    }
}
```

More about tuple type: [document](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Types.html#//appleref/swift/grammar/tuple-type)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
for name in namesDictionary {
    if namesDictionary[name.key] == highestOccurence {
        mostCommonNames[name.key] = highestOccurence 
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the if statement should be `namesDictionary[name.value] == highestOccurence` but yep, I see what you mean!

Comment: `namesDictionary[name.value]` will give you error because you need to pass key in `[ ]` not the value. `namesDictionary[name.key]` returns the value of key.